# Looking for efficient way to store HashMap<key,ArrayList<object>> in SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, arraylist, hashmap

I want to implement the following HashMap with SQL

```
HashMap<key, ArrayList<posting>>
```

The posting class definition is:

```
public class Posting {

 public int documentId;
 public double score;

 public Posting(int docId, double scr){
     documentId = docId;
     score = scr;

 }
 }
```

Then I create a table with name hashMap and with columns (keyId,key). The keyId is auto-increment Id. Also, each key only insert one time in the hashMap table.

Then I create a table with name posting. The columns of this table are (keyId, docId, score).

Do you think it is an efficient (space and time) way for implementing hashmap?

My second Idea is that I create a table with name hashMap and with columns (key, postingName) and key is the primary-key. postingName is the name of the table with columns (docId, score).
In the second implementation I convert each array list to a table.

Do you think which one is efficient?

Is there any better way to implement this hashmap?

Note that the size of my hashmap is so huge. I want to store about 16.3G data. I only want to store my HashMap to Mysql database then retrieve the data from database to HashMap.

I appreciate your ideas.

Comment: What is the type of `key`? If it is an integer, don't use a separate `keyId`. The overhead of that is 200% over just using `key` directly.

Comment: @Dark Falcon the type of the key is string.

Comment: Do you need it to be relational? That is do you anticipate having to run queries against your database to answer questions like "what is the average score for such-and-such docId?", "how many different docs are associated with this key?" etc. If not, you might be better simply serializing (and gzipping) the list, and storing it as a blob for each key, with a single table, like (key, blob). If you do need a relational schema, then your design does seem reasonable.

Comment: @DarkFalcon the number of document are 10000. I prefer I can have does information but could you please explain more about your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think creating a table with three columns(keyId, docId, score) is good. Then you can retrieve the results with select keyid, docid, score from table.   You  could then  build the hashtable in source.  Or you could do select docid, score from table where keyid = 40

Comment: your suggestion need lotf of space since the length of the ArrayList of posting is more than 10000 and the keyid should be written for all postings.

Comment: You  would not necessarily have to store the  results in a hashmap. It would  help  if you indicate the queries you  will need. For example, if you want o print outall results   you could read in  the table sorted by keyid and print them out  without storing anything. If  you want  just one  keyid then  you could read just  that  one in. Finally   10000 integers only takes up 40K, which isnt that large. But most likely  you  dont need to store the map.

Comment: I need to read data from sql and store in a hashmap becuase I only use sql to store my data instead of the file.

Comment: It would be helpful if you clarify what you are trying to do.